# Correct way to test an express apps API?

Tags: node.js, testing, express, mocha.js

I've found a way to do it, but my gut feeling tells me there should be some more idiomatic way of doing it. Basicly what I don't like is that i have to require the express app in the test-suite, which makes me wonder if there's a race-condition going on. Also, I wonder what would happen if I ran several testsuites in several files like this.

Anyone know a cleaner solution?

My simplified app is as follows:

app.js

```
app = module.exports = express()
...
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
     console.log('app listening');
});
```

test.js

```
var request = require('superagent');
var assert = require('assert');
var app = require('../app');
var port = app.get('port');
var rootUrl = 'localhost:'+port;

    describe('API tests', function(){
        describe('/ (root url)', function(){

            it('should return a 200 statuscode', function(done){
                request.get(rootUrl).end(function(res){
                    assert.equal(200, res.status);
                    done();
                });
            });
    ...
```

Comment: I use a module called supertest https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest which works well for this.

Comment: If you hardcode the port in your app, you're not going to escape from having to import it in your test if you want that sort of flexibility. You could consider using some sort of configuration framework (like the easy to use [`config`](https://npmjs.org/package/config)) which you can use from both your app and your test.

Comment: thanks @Brett , I went with your suggestion and it worked fine for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a module called supertest [github.com/visionmedia/supertest](http://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) which works well for this.

Answer (score 2):

mocha let's you start the server once for any number of tests by using the [root Suite](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/):

`You may also pick any file and add "root" level hooks, for example add beforeEach() outside of describe()s then the callback will run before any test-case regardless of the file its in. This is because Mocha has a root Suite with no name.`

We use that to start an Express server once (and we use an environment variable so that it runs on a different port than our development server):

```
before(function () {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
  require('../../app.js');
});
```

(We don't need a `done()` here because require is synchronous.) This way, the server is started exactly once, no matter how many different test files include this root-level `before` function.

We then also use the following so that we can keep the developer's server running with nodemon and simultaneously run tests:

```
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    port = process.env.PORT || 3500; // Used by Heroku and http on localhost
    process.env.PORT = process.env.PORT || 4500; // Used by https on localhost
  }
  else {
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Used by Heroku and http on localhost
    process.env.PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000; // Used by https on localhost
  }
```